# printing client side crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am doing a web application in .net with crystal report,
is there a way to print crystal report on client side and do some server side treatement
i'm using c#, asp.net (.net 2)?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'server side treatment'?

Comment: like updating columns in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the `CrystalReportViewer control` in your ASP.NET page then you can `PrintToPrinter` on that control... and print on client side...

Another option is create a PDF from the report and stream the PDF to client... the clients' PDF viewer will allow them to print...

IF neither of the above is an option in your case then you call some javascript function `window.print()` in your web page then the browser shows the printer dialog to the user...

Comment: i need to do both server side and client side treatment, after printing i would like to update a column in a table

Comment: there is no way to know whether the printing was "successfull" but you can always postback to the server after the print command was invoked on the client